# "Delete Build in Jenkins after Keep Forever"

Tags: jenkins, build, hudson

I've used the Simple Promote Plugin in Jenkins and it set my build to "*keep this build forever*".

Is there any way I can delete it?

I got access to the slave who build it and to the master (tried to find anything related in there but no luck).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as Christopher said, you can remove the build just by deleting the build directory on the master, inside the job directory.

However if you access the page again, the build data gets dumped to disk again. So you either shut down Hudson first, or you go to the Hudson management console and 'Reload Configuration from Disk' which basically discards whatever's in memory and reloads from your config files.

Just make sure you do it right after deleting the folder.

Comment: Thanks for that small detail Francisco. It was essencial. I wish I could make both answers (yours and Christopher) correct.

Comment: The idea on StackOverflow is to have *one* correct answer with all the info, so one of the answers here should really be edited to include all the information together. Anyway, glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure whether (or how) the Simple Promote Plugin affects this at all, but can't you just click the button that says "Don't keep this build forever", followed by "Delete"?

When a build is marked as "keep forever" (and the padlock icon shows next to the build), you should be able to "unlock" it by pressing that "Don't keep..." button on the build page.

Comment: Hi Christopher,

Thanks for your fast answer. I wasn't sure to so i promoted a few more builds to check for the pattern ant it happens as said.

Whenever I "promote" a build I loose the ability to delete it. And, as you said, I get the padlock icon. The problem is that the icon is just an icon. It's not clickable.

It has the usual tooltip "Keep This Build Forever" but i can't interact with it.

Comment: Ok. Normally if you click the build number/timestamp link (rather than the icon) to view its page, there should be a "Don't keep this build forever" button in the top right, where the "Delete" button normally is.

Comment: Yah, I know. But it's not there :/ honestly don't get it. Do u know of some way to delete it via back-end? Like going to the server and deleting some folders or manipulating some files? Once again, thanks for your interest.

Comment: Ok, fair enough :)  You can remove a build by deleting the named directory on the master under `$HUDSON_HOME/jobs/job-name/builds/42` (though that's from memory, so might not be exact).  If you just want to remove the artifacts, remove the `archive` subdirectory.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer your comment Christopher but I was expecting some kind of mail notification on new comments. I've tried that before but the build doesn't go away from the build list and when I click there the folder is created again on disk. But thanks anyway as I feel one step closer.

Comment: @Tiago: In order to use the "Don't keep this build forever" button you'll need to enable "Discard Old Builds" in the job's configuration.

Comment: I'm using 'promoted builds' plugin, and after promoting a build I cannot longer delete it. There is the lock icon, there is the Delete this build link, but after I press the link, it displays a warning that 'this build is explicitly marked to be kept' with no buttons to proceed. Even if I enable 'Discard Old Builds" option, it does not work. Only physically removing the correspondent build folder from Jenkins home dir worked.

Answer (score 6):

In order to delete builds marked "keep this forever" you should change that flag to opposite state.

Please follow next steps

1. Open within a text editor $HUDSON_HOME/jobs/job-name/builds/xx/build.xml
2. Change

   > <keepLog>true</keepLog> to <keepLog>false</keepLog>
3. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Reload Configuration from Disk

After these steps you will be able to delete build marked as "keep this forever"

Answer (score 1):

I think that the final (and may be the only one step) to completely delete build from Hudson's history is to modify "nextBuildNumber" file placed in job directory.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that "Don't keep this build forever" button will only appear when you enable "Discard Old Builds" inside job configuration. I am not sure if it affects Simple Promote Plugin, but it work in this way with 'Release Plugin'.

MichalT

Comment: I have "Discard Old Builds" checked in the config, but still don't see a "Don't keep this build forever" button (anywhere that I've looked)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about masters and slaves, but there is an answer here that allowed me to delete a build "explicitly marked to be kept".

[List all keep-forever builds in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626186/list-all-keep-forever-builds-in-jenkins#answer-9629742)