# List all keep-forever builds in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there an easy way in Jenkins to list all all builds marked as keep-forever?  And then, ideally, one click to either unmark the build as keep-forever or to immediately delete it?

In our process, we mark a build as keep-forever if it involves some specific type of failure; that's to keep Jenkins from automatically deleting over time.  I need an easy way to get a list of all those keep-forever builds so they don't take up all our disk space over time.

Comment: Also see: [How to display all keep forever build number using Jenkins REST API for a specific job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30853087/4850949)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following XPath query against Jenkins will list the URLs of all builds marked 'Keep Forever':

```
http://[jenkins_server]/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=/hudson/job/build[keepLog="true"]/url&wrapper=forever
```

Enter it in the browser and see what it returns.

Now, you can embed it into XSLT-based HTML to get a list with links to those builds. To delete the build you can provide a button that invokes Jenkins CLI:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[jenkins_server]/ delete-builds [job-name] [build-num]
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to disable 'keep build forever' with CLI without deleting it.

Comment: Works great - if your Jenkins isn't too big.  Unfortunately, the production Jenkins has several hundred jobs with a couple thousand builds.  The Java stack ran out of space.  But using the same idea, I could write a script that iterates jobs and builds and does the same thing.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for the same thing, and our jenkins is pretty big as well and trying the link:

```
 http://[jenkins_server]/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=/hudson/job/build[keepLog="true"]/url&wrapper=forever
```

I ended up crashing it.

But as it turns out I only require the last 'keep forever' build of one job at a time, which seems to work way faster. So I use the following instead:

```
http://[jenkisn_server]/job/[job_name]/api/xml/?depth=2&xpath=/freeStyleProject/build[keepLog="true"]/number&wrapper=forever
```

which returns the xml with all the numbers of build that are marked as 'keep forever'
You can modify the xpath to fit your needs.

Comment: I am not sure what I did wrong, this is what I would have thought helpful. Your comment is not very helpful either.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following pipeline to iterate over all jobs and all their builds and unmark a build if it is e.g. older than 90 days

```
def process_job_history(Map config = [:]) {
    // create default dict with some values
    def defaultDict = [
        verbose: false,
        olderThanDays: 30,
    ]

    // update the default map content with the user provided config content
    // new key/value of provided map is automatically added to the defaultDict
    defaultDict << config

    def counter = 0;
    
    // get the job by its name, this requires a non sandboxed job
    def job_name = defaultDict.job_name;
    def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job_name, Job.class);
    def all_builds = job.getBuilds();

    if (defaultDict.verbose) {
        println();
        println("Processing ${job_name}");
        // println("all_builds: ${all_builds}");
    }

    if (all_builds.size() < 1) {
        if (defaultDict.verbose) {
            println("No builds found");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    def today = new Date();
    def earlier_in_time = today - defaultDict.olderThanDays;

    // collect the history of builds, and print additional infos for each build
    all_builds.each { build ->
        // a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument
        if (build.getTime().compareTo(earlier_in_time) < 0 && build.keepLog) {
            println("${build.absoluteUrl}: ${build.id}, result: ${build.result}, date: ${build.getTime().format('YYYY-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss')}");

            // may "delete" (do not mark it as) keep forever
            // build.keepLog = false;
            
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Process job history") {
            steps {
                // ''' uses system variables like $HOSTNAME, $PWD, ...
                // """ uses groovy variables like someCustomVar
                script {
                    def counter = 0;
                    def job_age = 90;   // 90 days since today

                    Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {
                        counter += process_job_history([job_name: "${it.getFullName()}", olderThanDays: job_age]);
                    }
                    println("Counted ${counter} jobs older than ${job_age} days");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```