# How to display all keep forever build number using Jenkins REST API for a specific job?

Tags: jenkins

I read the following post which does what I want for all jobs (and I made it works)

[List all keep-forever builds in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626186/list-all-keep-forever-builds-in-jenkins)

**here is what I have now :**
http://jenkinsmediaprocessor:7880/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=/hudson/job/build[keepLog=%22true%22]/url&wrapper=forever

But **I only want to display a specific task**. However I don't know where to set the job name,

**I tried the followings**

1-) job/MYJOBNAME

2-) JOBPATH/job/MYJOBNAME

3-) replace job with MYJOBNAME

I can't make it works.

**Also** would it be possible to only display a list of number? Instead of having to use a grep on the *.xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=//build[keepLog=%22true%22]/number&wrapper=forever
```

Sample output:

```
<forever>
  <number>688</number>
  <number>687</number>
</forever>
```

`forever` is a wrapper parameter. You will find more details if refer to `JENKINS_URL/api`:

> For XPath that matches multiple nodes, you need to also specify the "wrapper" query parameter to specify the name of the root XML element to be created so that the resulting XML becomes well-formed.

Comment: thanks a lot! I try to understand the api, however when I just write this : JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/api/xml   why don't I see the forever property? I try to find which param to write after the xml keyword to have the build forever, but since I don,t see it in the full xml it's hard to find

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim `forever` is a wrapper parameter in query. It wraps your results if you have multiple nodes. That's because of xml can't have multiple nodes at the root. That parameter is not present in original xml but created to properly format response.

Comment: You can replace `number` by `url` (so for the above example that's `JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=//build[keepLog=%22true%22]/url&wrapper=forever`) to obtain the job urls, which I find more convenient than just the plain job numbers.